# Entity Framework With Sql Azure over net tcp slow performance

Tags: performance, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, nettcpbinding

Hy guys,

So i have a really big performance issue here. I have a WPF application which connects to a service which runs inside a Worker Role. The service uses net tcp binding with full duplex. The data access layer is all in a library which i am referencing in my service. So when my service want's to get data it uses the methods in that library. That library uses EF 4.1 which is mapped to an Sql Azure database.

The problem i am facing is that a query like getting a user from a database, takes somewhere above 4 seconds. I have also a http service(used by a Silverlight app) which uses the same dataaccess library, the same query over there takes 115ms, which is normal.

Is there a problem with the Entity Framework when i am using a net tcp service? I really don't know where the issue is, because over a http service all the queries behave normaly.

Comment: So regarding the problem, i narrowed this to something that has to do with worker roles. I have also another worker role that does operations on the azure sql database using the same library with EF4.1. This worker role has also performance issues regarding the queries. I am really confused here...

Comment: Are your roles and SQL database in the same affinity group? You absolutely want to make sure you're working in the same data centre. I'd also consider implementing a "stub" service method that does no data access to see if the net-tcp binding that has an issue somewhere.

Comment: Yes , the roles are in the same affinity group with the database. Well, i think the issue is not with the binding, because like i said above, i have another role that doesn't host a service, it only performs database operations, and the performance issue appears in this role also. Both worker roles are having the same problem, only the webrole(which hosts the Silverlight Web App with a basichttp service) works well without a problem. In all 3 roles i am using the same dataaccess library, with the same operations, only that, when i call them from worker roles the operations are very slow.

Comment: How many records does the query return? I have found using SQL Azure if you have a query that returns more than a few hundred rows it will be pretty slow.

Comment: And, how many queries does the library perform per request? We've found that even in the same data centre you can get latency of ~50ms or worse _per query_ -- so if you have a poorly-written bit of code that does queries in a loop you can get appalling performance. Shift the load to the database.

Comment: Well, the number of rows returned it's really not the problem. In my case i am talking about a query like this Context.TerminalUsers.Where(user => !user.IsDeleted && user.Mac == mac).FirstOrDefault(). This takes 4 seconds, when i am calling it from the worker roles. To be more precise, i am using a mangager in my worker role which instantiates a  specific repository(in this case a TerminalUserRepository), and the repository belongs to the dataaccess library. Each instance of a specific repository that i use in my manager, creates and uses it's own EF context.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you are using Lazy Loading instead of Eager loading with your entity?  Lazy Loading over the Internet is much slower since it results in many more roundtrips to SQL Azure, which would be the bottle neck in this case.  Eager Loading will simply get all of the data at once with a single round trip.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: I don't think it has to do with Lazy Loading. I tried this also , putting Lazy Loading false for the context but no effect. Like i said, i have a web role with a service, that works without performance issues using the same dataaccess library like the worker roles. Only when using the worker roles i am facing this problem.